# What is the value that the "b" term should have before the optimization problem starts?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I have been beating my head against this wall: There is this optimization problem for SVM (photo taken from Andrew Ng's lecture notes)
[image: Optimization problem]

What I did not get is how, by using a quadratic solver for example or even just as a phenomenon, the "b" value gets set initially. We are optimizing in respect to both w and b, so the algorithm has to find the best values of w and b that both minimize the quantity that depends just on w. Some forums stated that the value "b" gets calculated after, by computing the equations for support vectors,and i understood how to do it ,but how to get there in the first place if solving for w requires b to be set in the constraints in order to get the problem started?

Comment: This is a question about algorithms; and the answer depends on what algorithm you are using.

Comment: Can you give an example or anything?